# Find a sequence whose generating function is given.

Tags: generating-functions

> Chap4 q2) Of which sequence is $U(s)=(1-4pqs^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ the
>   generating function(where $0<p=1-q<1$)?

Solution: So we need to find out a sequence $u_0,u_1,...$ such that $u_0+u_1s+u_2s^2+...=(1-4pqs^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$. Given that $\sum_i ar^i=\frac{a}{1-r}$, I feel like I need to make the exponent of $(1-4pqs^2)$ be $-1$

Comment: Do you know the generalized binomial series expansion?

Comment: No unfortunately, my knowledge in math is very basic.

Comment: I know the Taylor and McLaurin expansion.

Comment: Oh sounds like a plan. I'll try

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial series:

$\begin{align*}
(1 + x)^{-1/2}
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{n} x^n \\
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2 n}} \binom{2 n}{n} x^n
\end{align*}$